# Commands runs in shell, but not in script: no directory found error

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sort, csv

I have a few commands that don't run as a script.

It's supposed to create a bulleted list of the file names, then sort the columns of each file alphabetically, grab the second and its matching third column and put them in HTML tags.  It works well for the most part, but doesn't successfully remove the .csv file extension.

Every time I run the script, it returns `line 10 p: No such file or directory found` and `line 21: /a No such file or directory found` repeatedly.

Update: It seems like it's an error with `sort` on my computer. I've run a simple shell script with only a sort comment and I get a `no such file or directory` error. I'm already on my `sudoers` list but maybe I'm doing something wrong. I don't understand why some people have commented that they have no problem running the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.csv; do
name=${file%.csv}
 echo "<li><a href='$file'>$file</a></li>" >> final.html
done
for file in *.csv; do
 name=${file%.csv}
 sort -t"," -k2 "$file" |
 awk -vfile="$name" -F"," '
 BEGIN {
 printf "<h3 id=\"%s\">%s</h3>\n", file, file
 printf "<ul class=\"no-bullet\">\n"
 }
 {
 printf "<li>%s (%s)</li>\n", $2, $3
 }
 END {
 printf "</ul>\n"
 printf "<p id=\"%s\" class=\"text-smaller block-looser\">[<a href=\"#top\">Return to Top</a>]</p>\n", file
 }
 ' >> final.html
done
```

When I have run `bash -x myscript.sh` I noticed that it eventually starts to return this:

```
 BEGIN {
 printf "<h3 id=\"%s\">%s</h3>\n", file, file
 printf "<ul class=\"no-bullet\">\n"
 }
 {
+ sort -t, -k2 file.csv
 printf "<li>%s (%s)</li>\n", $2, $3
 }
 END {
 printf "</ul>\n"
 printf ' 'id="%s"' 'class="text-smaller' 'block-looser"'
myscript.sh: line 9: p: No such file or directory
+ href='"#top"'
+ to Top
myscript.sh: line 21: /a: No such file or directory
```

I don't understand what the discrepancy is between running it in the shell versus the script especially when I run it in the same directory as my .csv files. These issues don't appear when the commands are pasted into the command line.

Update: running the code with a directory only makes the first for loop run but still has an issue going through the second loop.

I accidentally put down lines 10 and 22 instead of lines 10 and 21 and updated the post to reflect that. There might have been an extra line somewhere in an attempt to debug/parse out what's going on.

Here is a sample .csv file that I'm trying to run with this shell script.

Contacts.csv

```
ID,Name,State
1,John,NY
2,Rachel,SC
```

The expected output for this code:

```
<li><a href='Contacts'> Contacts</a></li>

<h3 id='Contacts'> Contacts </h3>

<ul class="no-bullet">

<li>John (NY) </li>
<li>Rachel (SC) </li>
</ul>

<p id='Contacts' class="text-smaller">[<a href="#top">Return to top</a>]</p>
```

I've also tried using `printf "<p` and `printf '<p` to no avail.

Second update:
The script still doesn't run as expected even when pasted from this post. I updated homebrew and tried a different machine but no luck. What could be going on???

Comment: It's displaying the *symptoms* of a quoting issue, such that `<p` and `</a` are being parsed as shell redirections rather than HTML entities

Comment: Is this the whole script? At first you mention errors in lines 10 and 22; then 9 and 20. This makes me suspect the script was edited during the creation of the question. Can you confirm the question is coherent? Post [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366988/10765659) if possible.

Comment: The error messages do not seem to correspond to the given code. It would be good to see an example input file and what you are trying to convert this into. That way we could suggest more robust ways of parsing the CSV and creating the XML output.

Comment: Consider copying and pasting your script from your question here and test run it. Then update the question with what your issue is.  Hint: The script currently presented script runs without issue given a comma-delimited simple CSV in the current directory.

Comment: I also don't see any error in the script.  It runs and produces the expected output.

Comment: "_I'm already on my sudoers list_" - what's the relevance of this please. I can't see any need for administrative rights in the context of your question

Answer (score 0):

You have just the name of files. That means the script is looking for files in "current directory", the one you `cd` into. Is it the same directory as the files you want to use?

Use absolute file names: `/somedir/someotherdir/filename` - that way you will always look for files in a known place.

Comment: Yeah, it's run in the same directory as the files. Should I specify the directory regardless?

Comment: Yes, define them. It wont hurt.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two ways that can lead to the problem description given in your question.

1. You edited the script *while it was executing*. Solution: don't do that
2. There is filesystem corruption that means your script file is being affected by other writers. Solution: force a filesystem check